# Slow the movement of circle collision resolution

Tags: javascript, geometry, game-physics, collision

I have written a collision detection and resolution system for the game I am currently working on. The collision resolution doesn't work quite as intended though. Occasionally I spawn one circle inside of the other, when this happens I'd like the inside circle to slowly move out of the other's diameter, but currently the code that I have working does it quite quickly and jarringly. It instantly teleports outside of the circle, rather than a slow transition.

I know that the code I am currently using tells the circle where it SHOULD be, so I just need to slowly move the circle to that position. But that is proving to be difficult.

I've tried a couple of solutions, one is included in the code below. I have also tried using linear interpolation to move the circle to its current position, to where the collision algorithm is telling it it should be. That didn't work correctly either.

```
//r is the radius of the circle
var dx = cell.x - cell2.x;
var dy = cell.y - cell2.y;
var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

if (distance < cell.r + cells2.r && cell.r > cells2.r){
var unitX = dx/distance;
var unitY = dy/distance;

cell.x = cells2.x + (cell.r + cells2.r + 1) * unitX;
cell.y = cells2.y + (cell.r + cells2.r + 1) * unitY;
//Ive tried below, but the results were not correct.
//cell.x += (cells2.x + (cell.r + cells2.r + 1) * unitX)*0.5;
//cell.y += (cells2.y + (cell.r + cells2.r + 1) * unitY)*0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move cell apart from cell2, you don't need to add cells2 coordinates

```
 cell.x += (cell.r + cells2.r + 1) * unitX;
```

To move slowly, make speed smaller

```
//calculate once:
v = 0.01 * (cell.r + cells2.r - distance);
// at every step:
cell.x += v * unitX;
```

Comment: The += was a typo I made while rewriting my code for stack overflow, thank you for pointing it out. After playing around with some values, your code is definitely working alot better, and gives me a good place to work off of. Its not perfect though, it moves a bit to fast and jarringly when first spawned inside of another circle, and a little too slow after getting closer to the end of the other circle. I want a more constant speed, I think. The collision also appears less precise when just running around bumping into other circles. I'll continue to work and see what I can think of.

Comment: To avoid deceleration, make stages as I wrote -  calculate speed only one time after spawning, and update position many times with the same speed